# Pull to refresh in flutter with iOS look and feel

Tags: ios, dart, flutter

I would like to add the pull to refresh behavior in my app. I read about the RefreshIndicator, but it seems to have only the material UI. Can you suggest me a way to have the native iOS pull to refresh in my Flutter App?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The native iOS-style pull to refresh widget is [`CupertinoSliverRefreshControl`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoSliverRefreshControl-class.html). You can check the official demo here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/cupertino/cupertino_refresh_demo.dart

Comment: That demo has moved here now: https://github.com/flutter/gallery/blob/master/lib/demos/cupertino/cupertino_refresh_demo.dart

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this package https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pull_to_refresh
It does what you need.

Add the dependency in your `pubspec.yml` file

```
dependencies:
     pull_to_refresh: ^1.1.6
```

Here you have the samples: https://github.com/peng8350/flutter_pulltorefresh/tree/master/example/lib/ui

Comment: Thanks for the help. I took a look at this library and its ok, but I'm looking for something native. I mean, for the Android platform you have the pull to refresh native behavior (i.e. https://codingwithjoe.com/flutter-implementing-pull-to-refresh) but I can't find the same widget for the iOS platform.